# I want to change color of text in one cell based on the color of text in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want a VBA program to change the color of text in one cell based on the color of text in another cell. For example:

If the color of text in cell A1 is blue. I want the color of text in cell B1 to be blue.

A formula or VBA program would help as I would need to do the same for a large number of cell.

Comment: What determines if `A1` is blue? Does it come to you that way, or is there perhaps a conditional format being used?  Is it only `A1` and `B1`? Or the *value* in `A1`, wherever it may appear in `B` column?

Comment: **pro tip**: If I see a post starting with "I want" and there is no code in it, I'll ignore it 99% of the time. Please show us what you've tried so far and what difficulties you've ran into. If you haven't tried anything yet, then Stack Overflow isn't the place for this question.

Comment: I agree with Macro Man.  Try to do it yourself, and if you get an error message, look that up... and when you get stuck, come back and ask a question about the error. That's how to get an answer quickly from this site.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Font.Color` property of specified cells.

```
Range("B1").Font.Color = Range("A1").Font.Color
```

Also you can use any variable for reusing.

```
Dim ColorTemplate As Long = Range("A1").Font.Color
Range("B1").Font.Color = ColorTemplate
Range("C1").Font.Color = ColorTemplate
...
```